# Duplicates picture on my android application

Tags: java, android, duplicates

I have an Android application that loading some information and one picture like a blog, but sometimes I got duplicates picture, I don't know what is the problem, but sometimes it works good.

Someone here can help me ?

Here's the code below:

> "endereco" is the URL of picture  and "view" is the context that I pass on the class that extends activity"

```
 public void loadImg(final View view ,  final String endereco){

        Thread nova = new Thread()

        {

            public void run() {
                Bitmap img = null;

                try

                {

                    URL url = new URL(endereco);
                    HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    InputStream input = conexao.getInputStream();
                    img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    Log.i("Funcionou","Foto: " + endereco);
                } catch (Exception ex){

                    Log.i("Erro",ex.toString());

                }

                final Bitmap imgAux = img;
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtfoto);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(imgAux);

                    }
                });
            }
        };

        nova.start();
        nova.currentThread().interrupt();



    }
```

Comment: Make sure you have not set any  android:background="@drawable/img" and use Asynck API call and bind bitmap in onPost.

Comment: Since you are new to Java and Android, I would suggest using `AsyncTask` provided by the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are downloading an image from a wbepage or server i wouldnt do it in a thread give it its own AsyncTask it gives you a whole load of methods that allow you to better control over what you are downloading and what to do with it after it has been downloaded.

Check out the Android dev [Docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I did,  but it's not working as I wanted,

I've made a new class, 
This class extends AsyncTask<ImageView, String, Bitmap> , 
 I used  a method called doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews),

 and there I called another method that I've made , this it called  download_Image(String url).

There, I make download of the picture, but it's working equal to loadImg.

Sorry my english is not very good.

Comment: Even using this class, I got duplicates picture